# Employee Directory (from AD) as webpart in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, custom-list, active-directory, directory

Perhaps I am missing it

Is there a way to create a employee Dir list that pulls from AD in sharepoint. all my users data is in AD and syncing to SP

I just need an easy way to concentrate it all into one list I can use in diffrent subsites.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want the synchronized data - from the userslist (/_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0) or do you actually want it from the AD?

Comment: its doesnt have to be directly from AD no but end of the day If I update someones phone number in AD it should "flow" into said list. (our sp is hosed by ms365 so local connections are pretty much out)

Comment: See if this Codeplex solution heplps you http://usersadbrowser.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

A very simple hack could be to show the list in a iframe
~site/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx?isDlg=1

(or make another view like this)
Goto ~site/_layouts/15/people.aspx - under settings|List settings
[image]

here you are in a regular list that you can add a view to. 
[image] 
then you can link to that instead of the simple.aspx

otherwise you could make a javascript webpart that got the users
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185012(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Option 1 doesn't give any option to change the view  all I can see is name, title and department

Comment: I have added an example on how you can change that.

Comment: I dont have the option for List settings.....It just seems odd that this isn't built into sp already as a corp tool

Comment: That's weird.. Note, that its under ~site/_layouts/15/people.aspx ? and yes it ought to be a listviewwebpart.

Comment: this is what im seeing  http://i59.tinypic.com/24dipuh.png